# app.post not working! "Cannot GET /up"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

i have a button in a `/index.jade` file that when pressed it executes

`window.location.replace("https://upload-andsize.glitch.me/up")` function.

the only thing it does is to redirect me from `/` to `/up` so far so good.

and if i make a get request all works fine but!..
a post request will not work

```
app.post("/up",function(req,res){
    res.send("hello-world")
})

 //will return Cannot GET /up
```

> server code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();


app.set("view engine","jade")
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){
  res.render(__dirname+"/views/index.jade",{})
  next()
})
app.post("/up",function(req,res){
  res.send("hi")
})

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

> jade code

```
html 
script(src= "client.js") 
title!=title
h1 upload a file and see its weight

input(type="file" id="myfile")

input(type="button" onClick="send()"  value="submit")
```

> client code

```
function send(){
  window.location.replace("https://upload-andsize.glitch.me/up")
}
```

Comment: what's the error you are receiving?

Comment: the error i get is Cannot GET /up

Comment: Please do provide detailed information, what you tried and what is the error you are getting and all the code that is involved with the problem.

Comment: ok if you can look at this now, and y the down vote?

Comment: `window.location.replace` will make a `GET` request to https://upload-andsize.glitch.me/up, which only accepts `POST`. What is `/up` going to do? Should it be `POST`? What will it return?

Comment: it should upload a file i answered my question already anyway ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem was a lack of understanding how does the routs work

the solution is that im not sending a **post request** but a **get request**

thats why im getting an error

changed the html to

```
form(action="/up" method="POST")
  input(type="file" id="myfile")
  input(type="submit"  value="submit")
```

and it all work well hope it will help others in future

Answer (score 0):

Please add `app.get('/up',(res,req)=>{})` method in your server code.